# Script that Automatically Does Something Every Day

Tags: backup, automator, osx-server, daemons

I'm looking for a way to automatically run a shell script or command every *time interval*. I'm running a server and I want to backup some folders every day. I don't want to use time machine because the backups need to be just the raw data.

How do I write a daemon/application/script that will do this? The commands I need to run are pretty simple, and theres more than one I need, so it'd be great if there was a semi-generalized way to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Macs running 10.5 or earlier, I'll use crontab.

On Macs running 10.6 and newer, I'll use launchd. More details here 
https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/launchd.plist.5.html

Comment: launchd has been available since v10.4.  BTW, another option is to drop the script in /etc/periodic/daily, and it'll be run every morning at 3:15am.

Comment: Is /etc/periodic is managed by crond or launchd?

Comment: @globalnomad: Thats exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: Gordon, agree with you launched has been available since 10.4 (there's a pull-down showing just that on the link I provided). I moved my cron jobs to launchd starting 10.6 and the transition was uneventful (which is a good thing).

Comment: Jason, starting with 10.6.6 /etc/periodic is managed by launched, in earlier OS X it is managed by cron.